# Microhttpd server doesn't want to send page

Tags: c, sqlite, server

I'm having a problem with microhttpd server which I can't solve by myself. I'm reading some data from SQLite database and I'm trying to format it in a json-like format and send it to client.

```
 rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, (void*)connection, &zErrMsg);
```

Callback:

```
int callback(void *connection, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<argc; i++)
    {
        char *display_page=malloc(1000); /* Size will be changed to fit, this is for testing.*/

        /* azColName = Name of the column in database */
        /* argv = value of the column*/

        sprintf(display_page, "{\"%s\":\"%s\",\"%s\":\"%s\",\"%s\":\"%s\"}\n", 
                                    azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL", 
                                azColName[i+1], argv[i+1] ? argv[i+1] : "NULL", 
                                azColName[i+2], argv[i+2] ? argv[i+2] : "NULL" );

        printf("disp page= %s\n", display_page);
        if (!send_page(connection, display_page))
            printf("failed\n");
        free(display_page);
        i+=2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

send page:

```
send_page (struct MHD_Connection *connection, char *page)
{
  int ret;
  struct MHD_Response *response;


  response =
    MHD_create_response_from_buffer (strlen (page), (void *) page,
                     MHD_RESPMEM_PERSISTENT);

  if (!response)
    return MHD_NO;

  ret = MHD_queue_response (connection, MHD_HTTP_OK, response);
  printf("ret = %d\n", ret);
  MHD_destroy_response (response);

  return ret;
}
```

output:

```
disp page= {"SUBJECT":"Todo1","DESCRIPTION":"asdf","URGENCY":"asdf"}

ret = 1
disp page= {"SUBJECT":"Todo2","DESCRIPTION":"NULL","URGENCY":"fdsa"}

ret = 0
failed
disp page= {"SUBJECT":"Todo3","DESCRIPTION":"qwer","URGENCY":"qwer"}

ret = 0
failed
```

It seems like the problem is somewhere in MHD_queue_response, but I have no idea why since I'm new into networking. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just an unrelated query, but why do `i++` in the `for` loop statement, and `i+= 2` in the loop body? Why not simply do `i += 3` inside the actual `for` statement?

Comment: Well, it was supposed to be 1 key/val pair per iteration, I have recently changed it and added i+=2 at the bottom. That would be corrected in refactor, but thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problems comes from `MHD_create_response_from_buffer` function call:

> memory management options for buffer; use MHD_RESPMEM_PERSISTENT if the buffer is static/global memory, use MHD_RESPMEM_MUST_FREE if the buffer is heap-allocated and should be freed by MHD and MHD_RESPMEM_MUST_COPY if the buffer is in transient memory (i.e. on the stack) and must be copied by MHD;

As you are enqueuing the response, you should copy the data (`MHD_RESPMEM_MUST_COPY` instead of `MHD_RESPMEM_PERSISTENT`):

```
  response =
    MHD_create_response_from_buffer (strlen (page), (void *) page,
                     MHD_RESPMEM_MUST_COPY);
```

Because the response may not be sent before you free the page.

Moreover, one http query will expect only **one** response. So you will have to construct a bigger page to send all at once:

```
int callback(void *connection, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
{
    int i;
    char *display_page = malloc(10000); /* Size will be changed to fit, this is for testing.*/

    for(i=0; i<argc; i+=)
    {
        char subpage[256] = "";

        sprintf(subpage, "{\"%s\":\"%s\",\"%s\":\"%s\",\"%s\":\"%s\"}\n", 
                                    azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL", 
                                azColName[i+1], argv[i+1] ? argv[i+1] : "NULL", 
                                azColName[i+2], argv[i+2] ? argv[i+2] : "NULL" );

        printf("subpage= %s\n", subpage);

        strncat(display_page, subpage, sizeof subpage-1);            

    }
    if (!send_page(connection, display_page))
        printf("failed\n");
    free(display_page);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is useful, and I applied it, but unfortunately it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: I think one query expect only one response. Answer updated.

Comment: Now it's happening something strange. Even tho 
"if (!send_page(connection, display_page))
        printf("failed\n");"
is not included into loop, it still loops 3 times. 

Output is same as before.

Comment: I may have found the cause of it repeating 3 times. 

It's because of "sql = "SELECT * from TODO";" TODO has 3 rows and thus it will call callback 3 times. Still can't figure out answer.